# $V= 3b + 2b^2$ - what's the value of $V$ when $b=4$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Do I multiply $4$ to the power of $2$ or do I multiply $8$ to the power of $2$? What is the answer? I'm thinking it's $76$.

Answer (score 2):

$$V=3b+2b^2$$

So, when $b=4$, we get $$V=3\times4+2\times4^2=12+(2\times16)=12+32=44$$

Answer (score 0):

You have $$3 \times 4+2 \times 4^2=12+2 \times 16=12+32=44$$